# Extract all similar words in a list in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a list  like below:

```
list="-list mail-username:123 --list mail-password:xyz --list url:https://www.google.com --list mail_username:123 --list mail_password:xyz --list mail_username:123 --list user_password:xyz"
```

I want to extract the values of all passwords and store it in a variable.

I tried using sed but couldn't get it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "similar"? What should the result be for this input? How do you know what's a "password" or not in that data?

Comment: You don't have a list, you have a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
pwds="$(echo "$list" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\n/g' | sed '/password/!d;s/^[^:]*password:\(.*\)$/\1/g')"
```

This will not work for passphrases with spaces, though.

Comment: Thanks @phranz, can you explain the second sed command?

Comment: The second sed will delete all lines not matching that pattern (password); so after that, there will be only the lines which contain actual passwords, and the last substitute command will replace these lines with them.

Answer (score 0):

This will include the trailing newline in the final password, but since you seem to be playing fast and loose with whitespace, that shouldn't be a problem.  (Or, at least, it's not more of a problem than the other issues that will crop up from being cavalier about whitespace!)

```
echo "$list" | awk '/password/{print $2}' RS=' '  FS=:
```